# VUE Js Cannot Scroll using router link

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, npm

My Page View cannot be scroll on mobile view if it was loaded from router link from different page, need to be refreshed then it can be scrolled.

this is how I call the page

```
<router-link 
:to="{ name: 'catalogue.categorizedproduct', params: { category: kategori.nama_kategori } }" style="text-decoration:none;">
<i class="bi bi-caret-right-fill"></i>category.category_name}}
</router-link>
```

there was 2 error, CORS and 'asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received' . Fixed the CORS problem but the other remain.

Comment: Is the `router-view` loading correctly? Your only problem is it cannot be scrolled?

Comment: correct @aceraven7, when i refreshed the screen it can be scrolled, only if i load the page via router link it cannot be scrolled